# Bootstrap interferes with the look/design of website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is what my website looks like before installing Bootstrap:

[image]

Then, using this code: `<.link rel="stylesheet" href=http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css` to install Bootstrap on my website, it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my **HTML** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Toontown Classic</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
    </div>

    <div class="contentLogo">

    </div>

    <div class="ContentIMG">
    </div>

    <div class="contentTEXT"
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-image: url("bg.png");
width: 100%
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
.wrapper {
width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.contentLogo {
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #666666;
background: #FFFFFF;
padding: 40px 300px; 
width: 300px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top: 10px;
}
.ContentIMG {
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #666666;
background: #FFFFFF;
padding: 40px 300px; 
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top: 17px;
}
.contentTEXT {
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #666666;
background: #FFFFFF;
padding: 40px 300px; 
width: 10px;
height: 300px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top: 25px;
right: -145px;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem u are facing...

Comment: And what problem were you trying to solve by installing Bootstrap?  Generally, you'd use Bootstrap for an entirely new page/site.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has default styling for html elements. Typically most people place their custom stylesheet after including the bootstrap styles and overwrite whichever styles they want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a grid system which is highly recommended.

Start by working with `rows` and `columns` and everything will fall in place.

Examples: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/